# Writing multiple queries for single Jasper report based on condition check

Tags: sql-server, jasper-reports

I am trying to generate one Jasper report in that I need to write query based on start and end date parameters. Here start and end dates might be null values, so based on start and end dates my query should change.

So far I have taken 4 parameters like `id, from, to, condition1, condition2 for condition1`

I defined an expression like

```
$P{from} != null ? "and date >= $P{from}:""  
condition2 expression $P{to} != null ? "and date < $P{to}:""
```

And my query is like this

```
select name from app_info where id=$P{id} $P!{condition1} $P!{condition2}
```

This query is giving all records even if I give date limits. I checked with my database and this output is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"and date >= $P{from}:"" not correct (check quotes)

Result string for expression like "and date >="+ $P{from}:"" makes no sense.

This solution for Oracle database. 
Expression for convert string to date for example : to_date('10.04.2008 10:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH:mi')

```
<parameter name="from" class="java.util.Date"/>
<parameter name="to" class="java.util.Date"/>
<parameter name="condition1" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{from} != null ? "and myDateField >to_date('"+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm").format($P{from})+"','DD.MM.YYYY HH:mi')":""]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="condition2" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{to} != null ? "and myDateField <=to_date('"+new  java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm").format($P{to})+"','DD.MM.YYYY HH:mi')":""]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

And parameter $P{condition1} must be declared after $P{from}. Order of parameters is important in this case (calculation second parameter by value first parameter)

HTH